# How Can I Upgrade Apache to the latest version in RedHat Enterprise Linux When Connected Via Putty

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, putty, redhat-satellite

I'm currently administering an Apache applications proxy on a RedHat server, The installed/running version of Apache is 2.4.6. I want to upgrade to the latest version securely. The httpd daemon is currently running on Server 7.9. How can I upgrade while connected via Putty. I'm new to linux, and would appreciate the steps.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 will reach end of life on June 30, 2024. You should be looking at upgrading the OS first, which will give you a more recent Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redhat 7.x will likely only ever have Apache v2.4.6 as it is Redhat policy to avoid major version updates of packages within a version of their OS, though the offered package has been updated with any security updates.

You do not mention which version of Apache you need to use, but Redhat 8.x offers v2.4.37 and Redhat 9.x offers v2.4.53 or v2.4.57.

Apache can be installed/updated on Redhat using `yum install httpd`